# react.js chrome browser related issue

Tags: javascript, html

when I am typing react.js code that is given in bucky's react.js tutorial series it is not getting executed but when pasting it from bucky's github repo. it is getting executed.....Can any one help me out please...and the code is.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
    creating component
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\hatim\Desktop\react\React-Boilerplate-master\src\js\react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\hatim\Desktop\react\React-Boilerplate-master\src\js\react-dom.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\hatim\Desktop\react\React-Boilerplate-master\src\js\browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="container_new"></div>

<script type="text/babel" >

var mycomponent=React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return(<p>this is new component </p>);

        }

});

ReactDOM.render(<mycomponent />,document.getElementById('container_new'));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can include the JavaScript files in the context of the location on your hard drive "c:\".  I think you need to be running them using a web server (IIS, Node, etc.) and then include them using relative or absolute web paths (http://localhost/mytest/src/js/react-dom.min.js).

Comment: issue is not that ...copying same code from his github repo works perfectly..but when I am writing (typing) the same code in my text editors it is not giving me the output